# ¿Cómo mostrar en orden un TreeView?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

Estoy usando una libreria TreeView: https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview.

Mi problema es que al hacer un ORDER BY id_ref_pcge se muestra normal pero en forma desordenada. ejmp:

[image: desordenado]

al ordenarlo por otro campo sale este error:

[image: error]

y lo que quiero es que se vea de forma ordenada. ejmp:

```
+01 - descripción...

+02 - descripción...

+03 - descripción...

+04 - descripción...

+05 - descripción...

...

+n - descripción...
```

Esté es mi código PHP (conta.php):

```
        case 'treeview':
            $data = array();
            $treeview = $contabilidad->getTreeView01();

            foreach($treeview as $row) { 
                $tmp = array();
                $tmp['id']         = $row['codigo'];
                $cta        = $row['cta'];
                $sub_cta    = $row['sub_cta'];
                $div        = $row['divi'];
                $sub_div    = $row['sub_div'];
                $analitica1 = $row['analitica1'];
                $analiticam = $row['analiticam'];
                $analitica2 = $row['analitica2'];
                $nivel      = $row['nivel'];
                $descripcion = utf8_encode($row['descripcion']);

                if ($nivel == 2) $descripcion = $cta . ' - ' . $descripcion;
                elseif ($nivel == 3) $descripcion = $cta . $sub_cta . ' - ' . $descripcion;
                elseif ($nivel == 4) $descripcion = $cta . $sub_cta . $div . ' - ' . $descripcion;
                elseif ($nivel == 5) $descripcion = $cta . $sub_cta . $div . $sub_div . ' - ' . $descripcion;
                elseif ($nivel == 6) $descripcion = $cta . $sub_cta . $div . $sub_div . $analitica1 . ' - ' . $descripcion;
                elseif ($nivel == 7) $descripcion = $cta . $sub_cta . $div . $sub_div . $analitica1 . $analiticam . ' - ' . $descripcion;
                elseif ($nivel == 8) $descripcion = $cta . $sub_cta . $div . $sub_div . $analitica1 . $analiticam . $analitica2 . ' - ' . $descripcion;

                $tmp['text']       = $descripcion;
                $tmp['parent_id']  = $row['ref_id_pcge'];
                array_push($data, $tmp);
            }

            foreach($data as $key => &$value) {
                $output[$value['id']] = &$value;
            }
            foreach($data as $key => &$value) {
                if($value['parent_id'] && isset($output[$value['parent_id']]))
                    $output[$value['parent_id']]['nodes'][] = &$value;
            }
            foreach($data as $key => &$value) {
                if($value['parent_id'] && isset($output[$value['parent_id']]))
                    unset($data[$key]);
            }

            echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
            //var_dump($data);*/
            break;
```

este es el código JS:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
     var treeData;

     $.ajax({
        url: 'conta.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
        opcion: 'treeview'
    },
    })
   .done(function(data) {
       $('#treeview').treeview({data: data});
   })
   .fail(function() {
   })
   .always(function() {
   });
 });
```

La tabla que contiene la información.

[image: Tabla]

Todo el código funciona correctamente lo único que quiero es que se muestre de forma ordenada. *espero su ayuda.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que veo en la imagen tu error esta es al utilizar el `ORDER BY` en el `SQL` ya que ordenas por `ref_id_page` y al menos todas las cuentas visibles **nivel 2** en dicho campo tienen el valor `0` por lo que luego el ordenamiento es 'aleatorio' por decirlo de algún modo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La solución seria que en la clausura `ORDER BY` utilices 2 campos para el ordenamiento (podría ser por `codigo` o `cta`)

ejemplo:

`SELECT * FROM tabla ORDER BY ref_id_page, cta;`

> En este caso, primero ordenaría por `ref_id_page` y después por `cta`

---

`SELECT * FROM tabla ORDER BY ref_id_page, codigo;`

> En este caso, primero ordenaría por `ref_id_page` y luego por `codigo`

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!! no me había dado cuenta de ese detalle.